# Can I save the keep the absolute path of a file in database?

Tags: ios, iphone

In my app I save some photos in sandbox and I keep its absolute path in database. Then I build and run again, I fetch the path and try to get the photo, it says the file doesn't exist.

At last, I found that every time I build and run my app, the path of app is different.

I use `NSTemporaryDirectory()` to get the temporary path, I run two times and get two results.

> /private/var/mobile/Applications/80E09BB5-5FEB-4C27-935E-E29DE7861392/tmp/
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/71427100-0DBF-42F0-B6B4-F88F6417292E/tmp/

Is it normal? When user updates my app, will the absolute path change?

If it's normal, should I just keep the relative path in database? Is there some best practice?

Comment: Yes it's normal. The character you see changing is due to "unique" and a mix with your app (with bundle id I think) and compile date. You have to get past this thing, and use `NSTemporaryDirectory()` for example (or others method like this one) that will give you already to "tmp".

Comment: @Larme When user updates its app, will the absolute path change ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a very bad idea to store the absolute path in the database as any updates to the app results in the app being stored in a different folder within `/private/var/mobile/Applications`.  During an app update, any files will be migrated across, however any references to them within the database will no longer be valid.

You must therefore always store the filepath *relative* to some other *logical* directory; for example the *Documents* or *Caches* folder.

This probably means you should store this path as a relative directory within your classes as well, and only resolve to an absolute path when you need to use it.

Finally storing temporary file references is probably a bad idea, as I believe any temporary or cached files can be removed from the filesystem by the O/S whenever it feels like it.  Therefore you should store these files in the *Documents* folder, using the techniques I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reference about the changing of the app's absolute path in apple's documentation?

Comment: There is some mention [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html) in the section *Files Saved During App Updates*.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't talk about the changing of the app's absolute path.

Comment: It states "iTunes installs the update in a new app directory".

Comment: Not that subtle at all. There is no hint in the docs saying that the absolute path will remain the same; instead, there are plenty of hints telling you to always use relative paths with the appropriate directories. Apple is very clear about where to store your data and how to get to those locations.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the file on server and store its physical path in database. I have built similar applications in past and that is how i used it. Might not be the right way but just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it normal?

Well, what is the meaning of temporary?

> When user updates my app, will the absolute path change?

Well, what is the meaning of temporary?

> If it's normal, should I just keep the relative path in database?

To do what with it?

> Is there some best practice?

Don't use a temporary path for persistent storage. What about the documents folder?

Comment: It's not the matter of temporary directory, the absolute path of documents folder also changes.

Comment: Yes, but the directory itself does not change.