# How to get partial file path after downloading with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, alamofire, nsfilemanager

I want to save the path of where I downloaded a file to my model object. Based on this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652894/xcode-changes-location-of-applications-folder-on-build), I should "only store the filename, and then combine it with the location of the documents directory on the fly". Well in my case it's the Application Support directory. I am not sure how to do this.

The full path of where the file will be downloaded is: `/Library/ApplicationSupport/com.Company.DemoApp/MainFolder/myFile.jpg`

`/Library/Application Support/` is the part I can't save anywhere and I have to get it during runtime from FileManager.

`com.Company.DemoApp/MainFolder/myFile.jpg` is part of that file path that I can store in database/config files.

However I do not know how to get this path: `com.Company.DemoApp/MainFolder/myFile.jpg` from `Alamofire` after downloading it. For example, here is the code to download the file, how do I get this path?

```
func destination(named name: String, pathExtension: String) -> DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination {
        let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
            let appSupportDirURL = FileManager.createOrFindApplicationSupportDirectory()
            let fileURL = appSupportDirURL?.appendingPathComponent("com.Company.DemoApp/MainFolder/\(name).\(pathExtension)")
            return (fileURL!, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }

        return destination
}

let finalDestination = destination(named: image.title, pathExtension: image.preview.pathExtension)

Alamofire.download(urlString, to: finalDestination).response { response in    
    if let imagePath = response.destinationURL?.path {
        /// I want to this path here: com.Company.DemoApp/MainFolder/myFile.jpg
        /// But not sure how to get it. How do I get this path?
    }
}
```

The problem is that `Alamofire` gives me the full path only: `/Library/ApplicationSupport/com.Company.DemoApp/MainFolder/myFile.jpg`. But I only want this part: `com.Company.DemoApp/MainFolder/myFile.jpg`.

Any ideas on how to get this path?

Also, Apple seems to refer to `Bookmark`'s if you want to get a file at runtime here: [Apple Docs for Bookmarks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW10)

Note this is a follow up to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655887/how-to-retrieve-nested-file-with-filemanager/41680995?noredirect=1#comment70584205_41680995).

**UPDATE 1**

This is one way I think this could work. (Based of an answer above).

```
enum DataDirectory: String {
    case feed = "com.Compnay.DemoApp/MainFolder/"
}

Alamofire.download(urlString, to: finalDestination).response { response in    

  let destURL = response.destinationURL!
        /// One way to save this path is to do so like this:
        myImageObject.partialLocalPath = "\(DataDirectory.feed.rawValue)\(destURL.lastPathComponent)"
    }
}
```

So I am saving the part in an `enum` and appending the `name` to it once the download finishes - then I add this to my model object for saving.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You already have the path here `let fileURL = appSupportDirURL?.appendingPathComponent("com.Company.DemoApp/MainFolder/\(name).\(pathExtension)")`, you should figure out how to reuse it. You don't need to retrieve it from `destinationURL`

Comment: @Joey Right, so I am reusing it in an `enum`, please see above my question under *Update 1*. Notice how I use the `enum` so that instead of retrieving what I need from `destinationURL`, I just recreate a string to save. Is this how you would do it? Thanks!

Comment: @Joey last thing, just ran into a case where I need to reuse that path in many places... seems like an `enum` is a good way so that I can access it in many places... if you agree you could post answer and ill accept